# Power BI - max date or nearest date of selected date

Tags: powerbi

Object: Sum up the nearest date's value by a given date

Here is my data

```
Table: MyData
+-------------------------------+
| ID     TradeDate        Value |
+-------------------------------+
| 1       2018/11/30      105   |
| 1       2018/11/8       101   |
| 1       2018/10/31      100   |
| 1       2018/9/30       100   |
| 2       2018/11/30      200   |
| 2       2018/10/31      201   |
| 2       2018/9/30       205   |
| 3       2018/11/30      300   |
| 3       2018/10/31      305   |
| 3       2018/9/30       301   |
+-------------------------------+
```

I create a table named 'DateList' and use slicer to select a specified date

[DateList Slicer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kheX.jpg)

**I want to achieve the result as follows:**

```
as of *11/9/2018*
+-----------------------------------+
| ID      TradeDate       Value     |
+-----------------------------------+
| 1       2018/11/8       101       |
| 2       2018/10/31      201       |
| 3       2018/10/31      305       |
+-----------------------------------+
| Total                   607       |
+-----------------------------------+
```

Currently, I try to use the steps to achieve the above result.

First, i want to find the nearest date from table 'MyData' use the new measure

```
MyMaxDate = CALCULATE(MAX(MyData[TradeDate]),Filter(MyData, MyData[TradeDate] <= FIRSTDATE(DateList[Date]) ))
```

Second, i create a new measure "MySum" to the sum up the values if [tradedate] equal to the "MyMaxDate"

```
MySum = CALCULATE(SUM(MyDate[Value]),Filter(MyData, MyData[TradeDate] = MyMaxDate))
```

Third, i create a matrix to show the result (see [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpZ3p.jpg))

Unfortunately, the result 1313 is different from my goal 607
So, how can i fix my DAX formula to achieve the right result?

Many Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. How does a slicer relate to the formula you post as `DateList = ADDCOLUMNS(CALENDAR...` ?? What is the logic IN PLAIN WORDS that if you select `11/9/2018` the result will be these three dates? Your question is not clear. Please provide more detail. Please edit your question to provide these details. Do not do that in a comment. Post a comment when you have updated your question to alert your followers.

Comment: Hi teylyn, thanks for your replay. I've been updated my question. Is that clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the closest date by taking a min over the difference in dates and then taking the minimal date with that minimal difference.

```
MyDate = 
VAR SlicerDate = MIN(DateList[Date])
VAR MinDiff =
    MINX(
        FILTER(ALL(MyData),
            MyData[ID] IN VALUES(MyData[ID])
        ),
        ABS(SlicerDate - MyData[TradeDate]))
RETURN
    MINX(
        FILTER(ALL(MyData),
            MyData[ID] IN VALUES(MyData[ID])
            && ABS(SlicerDate - MyData[TradeDate]) = MinDiff
        ),
        MyData[TradeDate])
```

From there you can create the summing measure fairly easily:

```
MySum = CALCULATE(SUM(MyData[Value]), FILTER(MyData, MyData[TradeDate] = [MyDate]))
```

[image: Result]